# Change in URL encoding of Cloud Endpoint parameters?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I recently upgraded my App Engine SDK from 1.8.4 to 1.8.8. This seemed to have changed how string parameters are coming into my endpoint methods on the development server. Previously they were already URL decoded for me. Now it seems I must do my own URL decoding of each string parameter. Was this an intentional change or maybe I am doing something wrong?

For instance, I have a simple method that essentially just echos a string.

A call to it looks like:

```
GET http://localhost:8088/_ah/api/sync/v1/echoMessage/hello%20world
```

Previously, I'd get the string parameter as "hello world" but now I'm getting "hello%20world".  This happens whether I use the Explorer API or in my generated Android client library.

Am I expected to do URL decoding of each string? That seems cumbersome and wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Update: The issue is not present in the production API code, just the development server.

Furthermore, rolling back the dev server to 1.8.4 fixed the issue. 

Should I consider opening an App Engine issue?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10341&q=Type%3DDefect&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log