# Google endpoints can't receive utf-8 chars in localhost

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm having encoding issues with Google Endpoint's requests

I send encoded utf-8 chars, but on the server I cannot retrieve them.
When you display the strings, you could see those strange symbols

The problems arise only in localhost.
Never with production Google App Engine servers

Is there a misconfiguration issue ?

**Request Header:**

```
Host: localhost:8888 
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-us,es;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
```

Comment: *** SOLVED *** The issue was the default Java character encoding of my JVM. As my OS is windows I must add a new environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS with value: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8. The default encoding for Windows is cp1252. Hope someone helps !!!

Comment: You're right!!!   Close and open your AndroidStudio after do that! Hope help others!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why (I feel like most of the cloud endpoints answers start this way), but when sending text to the local devserver try [URL encoding it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) beforehand:

In JavaScript:

```
var local = (location.host.indexOf("localhost") !== -1);
var url = (local) ? encodeURIComponent(article.url) : article.url;
```

<sup>Two [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167475/messed-up-character-encoding-with-android-gae-cloud-endpoints) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271020/change-in-url-encoding-of-cloud-endpoint-parameters) that need to be addressed.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but the issue isn't about to encode special URL chars like ,/? :@&=+$# My issue is about UTF-8 characters. The first question you link is very interesting: it was the same issue (but in Java instead of Javascript on the client)